# How to make a blue button with white text?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, uibutton, background-color

```
// Make text white... and background blue

[myButton setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[myButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
```

Should that make a button with white text... and a blue background?
It doesn't.

Comment: It looks like a button with no text at all.   And just the *CORNERS* of the button turn blue.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like your button is of the `UIButtonTypeRoundedRect` type. The link below should answer your question.

[Is it even possible to change a UIButtons background color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2808888/is-it-even-possible-to-change-a-uibuttons-background-color)

What I do however is just not give it a type.

```
UIButton *myButton = [[UIButton alloc] init];
[myButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
[myButton setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Doesn't look quite as fancy like that though.

Answer (score 0):

What's the buttonStyle on that button?  That'll affect how the color settings make it look.  You might try different button styles until you find one that looks right.