# Change pressed color of UIButton

Tags: ios, uibutton

Is there any way to change the color of a UIButton when it's pressed?

The default seems to be a blue color, but I don't see where or how to change this to a custom color.

Thanks!

Comment: That one is referenced from the one I linked. There are several possible duplicates really. Pick one. :) Either way, vote to close as a duplicate.

Comment: I did. And yes you are are right.

Comment: rob you should give resonance of your question's answer given by other SO user..

Comment: i don't Understand why People not reply after asking Question..? here all given total 7 answer yet but @rob not replay at-list one answer's of his Question.. :@

Comment: As stated there are several valid answers. I replied in detail below.

Comment: Hey, [I made a category that helps you to achieve this](https://github.com/NSElvis/UIButton-ANDYHighlighted).

Comment: See [how to use `setBackgroundImage(...)` to achieve this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15440165/8740349), without real image!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ultimately followed the following poster's suggestion. It worked perfectly.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10670141/720175

In my particular case I created a subclass of UIButton, with the final code as:

```
-(void) setHighlighted:(BOOL)highlighted
{
    if(highlighted) {
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1 green:0.643 blue:0.282 alpha:1];
    } else {
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1 green:1 blue:1 alpha:1];
    }
    [super setHighlighted:highlighted];
}
```

Easy as pie.

Comment: answer is outdated and won't work. Use  `[mButton setTitleColor:[UIColor blueColor] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];`

Comment: @MarcinDeszczynski I guess this changes only the title's color?

Answer (score 6):

If you are using storyboard then in inspector window you can change the `highlight tint` property to the color you want on button click event.
[image: highlight tint]

Look at the `Highlight Tint` property in image.

Comment: This property does not exist in xcode5.

Comment: Thanks to this hint given here, I was able to use .tintColor to set the color (as of Xcode 7.1). E.g. let button = UIButton(type: .System)
button.title = "My Title"
button.tintColor = .redColor()