# How to change selected segment tintColor of UISegmentedControl in Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uisegmentedcontrol

I want to change the **tintColor** of UISegmentedControl selected segment in Swift 3.
I've searched a lot of answers in Objective-c...
This is my code:

```
class ViewController:UIViewController{

var segment:UISegmentedControl

override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()

segment.insertSegment(withTitle: "AAA", at: 0, animated: true)
segment.insertSegment(withTitle: "BBB", at: 1, animated: true)
segment.insertSegment(withTitle: "CCC", at: 2, animated: true)

segment.addTarget(self, action: #selector(changeValue), for: .valueChanged)
segment.selectedSegmentIndex = 0

view.addSubview(segment)

}
  func changeValue(sender:AnyObject) {

  //I don't know how to do that change color when segment selected
  // 

}

}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Here is a beautiful article to customize segmentedControl :) http://smnh.me/customizing-appearance-of-uisegmentedcontrol/ I believe you will have to subclass the UISegmentedControl change the background image for various states :)

Comment: You can take reference from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29312447/how-to-set-uisegmentedcontrol-tint-color-for-individual-segment

Comment: @imbeginner_sorry pls check my answer and reply..

Comment: just add tint color to the UISegmentControl like :  

segment.tintColor = UIColor.green

Comment: Please check the answers and reply!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To programmatically change tint color of segment,

segment.tintColor = UIColor.yellow

Answer (score 10):

Use the code below for above ios 13,

```
if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
        segment.selectedSegmentTintColor = .red
} else {
        segment.tintColor = .red
}
```

Answer (score 5):

if you want to set the color of the title for example, you can do it like this:

```
let titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: Color.blue]
segmentedControl.setTitleTextAttributes(titleTextAttributes, forState: .Selected)
```

Comment: Its the solution for just changing the selected segment title.

Answer (score 2):

In Main.storyboard, select segmentControl and change the property "Tint" as shown in below screenshot:

[image]

If you create the segmentedControl programmatically, then use this:

```
 segment.tintColor = UIColor.red
```

Answer (score 1):

A new property was added in iOS 13: [selectedSegementTintColor](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uisegmentedcontrol/3335209-selectedsegmenttintcolor). The old tintColor property no longer works in iOS 13.

You can find a more complete writeup of the changes here [iOS 13 UISegmentedControl: 3 important changes](https://medium.com/flawless-app-stories/ios-13-uisegmentedcontrol-3-important-changes-d3a94fdd6763)

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code to your `changeValue` function:

```
func changeValue(sender: UISegmentedControl){
for i in 0..<sender.subviews.count {
    if sender.subviews[i].isSelected() {
        var tintcolor = UIColor.red // choose the color you want here
        sender.subviews[i].tintColor = tintcolor
    }
    else {
        sender.subviews[i].tintColor = nil
    }
}
}
```

This is a swift version of the accepted answer from this question: [UISegmentedControl selected segment color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2270526/uisegmentedcontrol-selected-segment-color)