# How can I change the top border of my UITabBar?

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I'd like the UITabBar to have a top border of width 5.0. The border should be yellow color.
I don't want any left/bottom/right borders.

The Tab Bar border should be flat (no shadows or anything like that).

How can I remove shadow (image) line?

Comment: Create you own TabBar SubClass and make an Overlay with top border on it.

Answer (score 48):

You can hide the top border this way in your FirstViewController.swift:

```
self.tabBarController!.tabBar.layer.borderWidth = 0.50
self.tabBarController!.tabBar.layer.borderColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
self.tabBarController?.tabBar.clipsToBounds = true
```

And result will be:

Before:

[image: before - top border is visible]

After:

[image: after - top border is not visible]

Hope it helps.

**EDIT:**

You can set background image this way:

```
UITabBar.appearance().backgroundImage = UIImage(named: "yourImageWithTopYellowBorder.png")
```

Comment: This hides the top border, but I want a border with color.

Comment: I think you can set background  image now which have top border with yellow color.

Comment: Thanks. What dimensions should the image be?

Comment: The default tab dimensions are 320x49 - https://www.google.co.in/search?q=tab+bar+size+ios8&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=dUDlVdz1GsHuugT-nIGIAg

Comment: Thanks - no other solution on S) (which does not use a private api) worked for iOS9 except this.

Comment: Work perfectly!

Comment: Not worked for me, i tried all the ways you suggested in your Answer, I wrote in the firstVC under the tabbar and inside the tabbar itself 

Comment: Doesn't work now. Swift 4,5. The same margins, borders as before.

Answer (score 10):

If you want to completely remove tab bar, put this in your AppDelegate:

```
UITabBar.appearance().shadowImage = UIImage()
UITabBar.appearance().backgroundImage = UIImage()
```

Answer (score 10):

This is how I get it done. I added a subview on top of the UITabBar.

```
let lineView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width:tabBarController.tabBar.frame.size.width, height: 1))
lineView.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
tabBarController.tabBar.addSubview(lineView)
```

Comment: Nice solution although the description is wrong since the UIView will be placed inside the `UITabBar` and not on top of it. Also `lineView` should be a `let` since it's never mutated.

Answer (score 6):

This is the complete solution, compiled of different SO answers, that worked for me (**Swift 3**):

```
// The tabBar top border is done using the `shadowImage` and `backgroundImage` properties.
// We need to override those properties to set the custom top border.
// Setting the `backgroundImage` to an empty image to remove the default border.
tabBar.backgroundImage = UIImage()
// The `shadowImage` property is the one that we will use to set the custom top border.
// We will create the `UIImage` of 1x5 points size filled with the red color and assign it to the `shadowImage` property.
// This image then will get repeated and create the red top border of 5 points width.

// A helper function that creates an image of the given size filled with the given color.
// http://stackoverflow.com/a/39604716/1300959
func getImageWithColor(color: UIColor, size: CGSize) -> UIImage
{
    let rect = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), size: CGSize(width: size.width, height: size.height))
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, 0)
    color.setFill()
    UIRectFill(rect)
    let image: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return image
}

// Setting the `shadowImage` property to the `UIImage` 1x5 red.
tabBar.shadowImage = getImageWithColor(color: UIColor.red, size: CGSize(width: 1.0, height: 5.0))
```

Answer (score 4):

**SWIFT 3**

I needed border colors (and line colors and weights) to match other elements in my app, so this worked for me in my custom UITabBarController's viewDidLoad:

```
tabBar.layer.borderWidth = 0.3
tabBar.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red:0.0/255.0, green:0.0/255.0, blue:0.0/255.0, alpha:0.2).cgColor
tabBar.clipsToBounds = true
```

Comment: not the right answer, this adds border to bottom, left, right and top

Answer (score 3):

```
    UIView *borderLine = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, screenWidth, 5.0)];
    borderLine.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];  
    [self.tabBarController.tabBar addSubview:borderLine];
```

This is the way to add border to a `UITabBar` which I follow.
It works cool.

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 4.2**

```
self.tabBarController!.tabBar.layer.borderWidth = 0.50
self.tabBarController!.tabBar.layer.borderColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
self.tabBarController?.tabBar.clipsToBounds = true
```

Just change border color as you want.

Answer (score 0):

There is a property named `shadowImage` that was introduced in iOS 6. You can change this to change the top border. For example, you can use a 1x1px image with a single colour to change the top border to that colour:

```
UITabBar.appearance().shadowImage = UIImage(named: "TabBarShadow")
```

You can also set it as just `UIImage()` to completely remove the top border.

```
UITabBar.appearance().shadowImage = UIImage()
```

To answer your question of a 5px border, this can be done by using a 1x5px image. There does not appear to be a limit on the size of the image and it will just repeat (so you could have a dotted line for example by having a 4x5px image where the first 2x5px are black and the next 2x5px are transparent). Note that if you use this, it is outside the bounds of the UITabBar so content will go behind the image unless you change the view bounds.

Answer (score 0):

It's a shadow image (property) of tabbar. Try following solutions and see.

** Swift **

```
//Remove shadow image by assigning nil value.
UITabBar.appearance().shadowImage = nil

// or 

// Assing UIImage instance without image reference
UITabBar.appearance().shadowImage = UIImage()
```

** Objective-C **

```
//Remove shadow image by assigning nil value.
[[UITabBar appearance] setShadowImage: nil];

// or 

// Assing UIImage instance without image reference
[[UITabBar appearance] setShadowImage: [[UIImage alloc] init]];
```

Here is apple guideline for [shadowImage](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitabbar/1623452-shadowimage).

```
@available(iOS 6.0, *)
open var shadowImage: UIImage?
```

> Default is nil. When non-nil, a custom shadow image to show instead of
>   the default shadow image. For a custom shadow to be shown, a custom
>   background image must also be set with -setBackgroundImage: (if the
>   default background image is used, the default shadow image will be
>   used).

Answer (score 0):

Firstly create an extension of UIImage as follow

```swift
extension UIImage {
    func createSelectionIndicator(color: UIColor, size: CGSize, lineWidth: CGFloat) -> UIImage {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, 0)
        color.setFill()
        UIRectFill(CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: lineWidth))
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return image
    }
}
```

In your view controller add the following code.

```swift
let tabBar = self.tabBarController!.tabBar
tabBar.selectionIndicatorImage = UIImage().createSelectionIndicator(color: UIColor.blue, size: CGSize(width: tabBar.frame.width/CGFloat(tabBar.items!.count), height: tabBar.frame.height)   , lineWidth: 5.0)
```

Answer (score -1):

Just set the UITabBar backgroundImage and shadowImage to be clear color:

```
tabBar.shadowImage = UIImage.init(color: UIColor.clear)
tabBar.backgroundImage = UIImage.init(color: UIColor.clear)
```