# Remove image of UIBarButtonItem programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, uibarbuttonitem

I have a `UIBarButtonItem` with an image I setup in the `storyboard`. Later on in the program, I want to change the `barButtonItem` to have text, and not an image. Here's the code:

```
self.menuBarButton.setBackgroundImage(nil, forState: .Normal, barMetrics: .Default)
self.menuBarButton.title = "Some Text"
```

When I run the app, the `barButton` shows the image, and 3 dots. "...". What can I do to remove the image, and have text instead?

Comment: Maybe try to create an image of clearColor using [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26542035/create-uiimage-with-solid-color-in-swift#answer-26542235) function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just set the `.image`-Property nil:

```
self.menuBarButton.image = nil;
```