# UITabbarItem default color swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbar

hi i want to change the unselected bur item color to white and i wrote this code :

```
for item in self.tabBar.items as [UITabBarItem]! {
        if let image = item.image {
            item.image = image.imageWithColor(UIColor.whiteColor()).imageWithRenderingMode(.AlwaysOriginal)
        }
    }
```

but i gives me this error in the first line :

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

what should i do?

Comment: Are you using a custom image as Tab Bar Item Icon or a System Image?

Comment: Please expand your question with more of your code. A simple iteration like "for item in self.tabBar.items! {}" works well in a standard UITabBarController if there are tabbar items

Comment: @Ishanhanda no i'm using custom images

Comment: @peacer212 yes i know and it used to work but when i added local notification, it stopped working. i don't know why because these two are totally irrelevant.

Comment: I can't really help you because I can't reproduce the error. Could you make a [GIST](https://gist.github.com/) with a more complete code example?

Comment: @peacer212 sure. but before that, is there any other way to make the tabBarItems white?

Comment: Your approach works fine, I just tested it with the `getImageWithColor `  function of this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26542035/create-uiimage-with-solid-color-in-swift)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a minimum code example that works for me

```
class MyTabBarController : UITabBarController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        if let items = self.tabBar.items {
            for item : UITabBarItem in items {
                if let image = item.image {
                    item.image = getImageWithColor(UIColor.whiteColor(), size: image.size).imageWithRenderingMode(.AlwaysOriginal)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    func getImageWithColor(color: UIColor, size: CGSize) -> UIImage {
        let rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, 0)
        color.setFill()
        UIRectFill(rect)
        let image: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return image
    }

}
```

The `getImageWithColor` function is taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26542035/create-uiimage-with-solid-color-in-swift). In case you also want the selected tabs to be white squares, set the `item.selectedImage` property as well.

Comment: this works kinda right but it made a white box instead of changing the icons to white

Comment: ok i fixed it. i changed the function a little bit and now it works fine. thanks.

Comment: I'm glad it worked this way. Could you update your question the code you used for future references?