# UISearchBar scope bar background image settable, but not its color?

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar

```
    for subView in searchBar.subviews {
        if let scopeBar = subView as? UISegmentedControl {
            scopeBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
        }
    }
```

I've been trying the above code to attempt to get a reference to the scopeBar and subsequently set its background color, but I am not able to get a reference. It seems to only go through the loop once, implying that there is only a single subview for the search bar.  In the debugger the search bar appears to have an instance variable called _scopeBar with a type of (UISegmentedControl *).

```
    if let topView = searchBar.subviews.first {
        for subView in topView.subviews {
            if let cancelButton = subView as? UIButton {
                cancelButton.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
                cancelButton.enabled = true
            }
        }
    }
```

The second block of code works for accessing the cancelButton of the search bar.

Answer (score 9):

You can set the scopeBar background image as a solid color image.

First, you will need to [create an UIImage from a color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26542035/create-uiimage-with-solid-color-in-swift). In order to do that, you can create a function, or an [extension on the UIImage](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29872390), such as the following code:

Swift 3

```
import UIKit

extension UIImage {
    class func imageWithColor(color: UIColor) -> UIImage {
        let rect: CGRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1, height: 1)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSize(width: 1, height: 1), false, 0)
        color.setFill()
        UIRectFill(rect)
        let image: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return image
    }
}
```

After that, you can simply set the backgroundImage on the scope bar:

Swift 3

```
// Set the scopeBar's background color:
searchBar.scopeBarBackgroundImage = UIImage.imageWithColor(color: UIColor.blue)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a sample issue, and I solved this as below code.

```
CGSize imageSize = CGSizeMake(64, 64);
UIColor *fillColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:228/255.0 green:228/255.0 blue:228/255.0 alpha:1.0];
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imageSize, YES, 0);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
[fillColor setFill];
CGContextFillRect(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, imageSize.width, imageSize.height));
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

self.searchController.searchBar.scopeBarBackgroundImage = image;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
- (void)changeScopeBarColor {
NSMutableArray<UIView*> *views = [NSMutableArray new];
NSArray<UIView *> *subviews = [_searchBar subviews];
[views addObjectsFromArray:subviews];
for (;;) {
    if (views.count == 0) {
        break;
    }

    UIView *v = [views firstObject];
    [views removeObject:v];

    if ([[[v class] description] isEqualToString:@"_UISearchBarScopeBarBackground"]) {
        v.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        break;
    }
    if (v.subviews.count > 0)
        [views addObjectsFromArray:v.subviews];
    }
}
```