# How to set scope Color and how to hide icon in searchbar in swift4

Tags: ios, scope, swift4, searchbar

I have two question.

It's my code

```
 func searchBarSetup() {

    searchBar.showsScopeBar = true
    searchBar.scopeButtonTitles = ["Name","Effect","Component"]
    searchBar.selectedScopeButtonIndex = 0
    searchBar.delegate = self
    searchBar.showsCancelButton = false
    let darkRed = UIColor(red: 0.392, green: 0.012, blue: 0.020, alpha: 1.00)
    searchBar.tintColor = darkRed
    self.navigationItem.titleView = searchBar
    //UINavigationBar.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISearchBar.self]).leftView = nil
    //UINavigationBar.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISearchBar.self]) = nil
    //searchBar.text = searchmodel.searchText

}
```

[image]

I set scope Color but my scope color consistently blocked. So search scope backgorund color look like dark. how to change scope background color.

and when i set search bar on view i can hide magnifying glass. but now i set search bar on navigation. so can't hide magnifying glass using this code.

```
 UINavigationBar.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: UISearchBar.self]).leftView = nil
```

I need your answer. Thanks

Comment: see this it helps you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34809547/uisearchbar-scope-bar-background-image-settable-but-not-its-color

Comment: Thanks!!! i solved this problem (scope backgroundColor)

Comment: welcome , happy to hear