# UISearchBar minimal style has transparent background

Tags: uisearchbar, transparent, uisearchcontroller

I've a `UISearchBar`added to the top of an `UITableView`.

```
        // init search bar
    self.resultSearchController = ({
        let controller = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
        controller.searchResultsUpdater = self
        controller.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        controller.searchBar.sizeToFit()
        controller.searchBar.tintColor = Config.grayColor()
        controller.searchBar.searchBarStyle = UISearchBarStyle.Minimal

        self.tableView.tableHeaderView = controller.searchBar

        // set content offset for table view in order
        // that the searchbar is hidden at the beginning
        self.tableView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: controller.searchBar.frame.size.height)

        return controller
    })()
```

This basically looks like expected:

[image]

But when I enter the search textfield and scroll down the table view it looks weird. The background of the search controller is transparent.

[image]

I've tried to set `barTintColor` and `backgroundColor` but it doesn't have any effect.

Comment: Any updates on this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57746292/navigation-bar-becomes-white-when-a-uisearchcontroller-is-added-to-it

Answer (score 2):

set the searchBar's backgroundColor to white

searchBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow and thanks for your help. You might want to make your answer even better by adding some explanation.

Answer (score 2):

I tested almost everything. The only way that worked for me is:

```
searchController.searchBar.searchBarStyle = .minimal
searchController.searchBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(color: .white), for: UIBarPosition(rawValue: 0)!, barMetrics:.default)
```

This works in both "normal" and "presented" forms. `UIImage(color: .white)` is just a way to create a 1x1 colored image that will be used to fill the background. You can find and implementation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26542035/create-uiimage-with-solid-color-in-swift/33675160)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code. This works for me:

```
UITextField.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf:  
      [UISearchBar.self]).backgroundColor = UIColor.RGB(red: 230, green: 230, blue: 230)
```

`UISearchBar` has a `UITextField` property and you just change that color like above.

Answer (score 0):

the only solution that worked for me **in Swift 5**:

```swift
func viewDidLoad() {
  // make content disappear when it touches searchBar
  edgesForExtendedLayout = []

  // make searchBar color non-transparent
  searchBarController.searchBar.backgroundColor = .red
}
```