# Navigation bar becomes white when a UISearchController is added to it

Tags: ios, swift, ios13

When I add a UISearchController to a UINavigationItem from an UINavigationController; it becomes white when the view loads and changes to the color specified when the user clicks on the search bar. This happened since ios 13.1. This video shows the behaviour:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/OhgFQ.jpg

My code consists of a simple storyboard with a NavigationController + a TableViewController, and the NavigationController has a color assigned to it:
[image]

The ViewController consists of the following code:

```swift
class ViewController: UITableViewController {

    let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
        searchController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        navigationItem.searchController = searchController
    }
}
```

I also added these keys to the `info.plist` file to force the app into light-mode, but if I remove these the same behaviour is still present:

```
<key>UIUserInterfaceStyle</key>
<string>Light</string>
```

This was tested on an iPhone XS Max, running iOS 13.1 beta 1. Is this expected behaviour or a bug which needs to be fixed?

Comment: Do you want to navigation bar all-time red and Do you want to search bar in navigation bar?

Comment: @YunusKarakaya Yes I want the navigation bar at all times to be red; and also have the searchbar in the navbar.

Comment: Unfortunately I have the same behavior on iOS 13.1

Comment: @Devxln Do you fix it ?  I have the same issue.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It looks like it is required to use the new UINavigationBarAppearance on iOS 13. Try to add this to your viewDidLoad:

```
let appearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
appearance.backgroundColor = .systemRed
appearance.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor : UIColor.white]
navigationItem.standardAppearance = appearance
navigationItem.scrollEdgeAppearance = appearance
```

You will probably also want to set the searchField backgroundColor:

```
let searchField = searchController.searchBar.searchTextField
searchField.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
```

Answer (score 6):

This appears to be a bug in iOS 13.1. Specifically, there is a new iOS 13 specific appearance (UINavigationBarAppearance) for navigation bars which specifies the appearance when the scroll view is scrolled to the top, along with the default state. Normally changes like this only go into effect when the app is built with the corresponding SDK (iOS 13.1). However, there seems to be a bug where the behavior also occurs when an app is built using the iOS 12 SDK.

See: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationbarappearance

Update:
There is a workaround here: https://itnext.io/fixing-issues-caused-by-future-sdks-ae0896384abf

Essentially, if your app is running on a device running iOS 13, it's possible to create instances of the new classes via NSClassFromString() in swift, then use a bit of objective-c runtime magic to configure the navigation bar.

Comment: Okay, and there’s no way for a temporary fix?

Comment: No. We cannot cause UIKit to behave differently depending on what SDK is used. 

A work around is to change the navigation bar's internal background view, but that depends on the particular structure of the navigation bar's view hierarchy, which is an implementation detail and could change at any time.

Comment: Developers are reporting this issue is resolved in iOS 13.2.

Answer (score 3):

What you want was not clear in your question. If you want, however, add searchbar into navigationBar and with a specific color this might help you.

The process of placing seachbar into navigation bar:

```
let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
navigationItem.searchController = searchController
```

You can add whatever controller you want into 'searchResultsController' value.

If you want to set background color into a specific color, you can change the bar tint from Storyborad -> navigationbar -> navigation bar attiribute inspection.

Also, this below code for the  AppDelegate.swift file will do the same. 'tintcolor' and 'titletextcolor' is commented

```
  func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.

        let navigationBarAppearace = UINavigationBar.appearance()
        navigationBarAppearace.barTintColor = UIColor.blue

        // navigationBarAppearace.tintColor = UIColor.red
        //navigationBarAppearace.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.red]
        return true
    }
```

Comment: Hi, sorry but this is not an answer to my question either; it has to do with ios 13. Since ios 13 the behaviour as I described occurs. Even if I add those global color values in AppDelegate.

Comment: I added to the post that this issue occurred since ios 13.1.

Comment: @Devxln I downloaded beta 13.1 but I did not encounter an unexpected behaviour

Answer (score 0):

I'm experiencing same issue, and already opened a radar to Apple.
Even though, if you set the backgroundColor to the appearance of the UINavigationBar, then the navigation bar instead of becoming transparent when pulling down and showing the search bar becomes that color, but then the status bar still remains white.

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = .white
UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = .blue
UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor : UIColor.white]
UINavigationBar.appearance().backgroundColor = .red
```

Here is some code that tries to mitigate that behaviour, but I'm open to hear for the status bar thing