# iOS13: UINavigationBar gets transparent when pulling to reveal UISearchController searchBar

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller, ios13

Testing one of my apps on the latest iOS 13.1 Beta 3 (using Xcode 11 GM Seed) I noticed that the NavigationBar gets transparent when pulling down an UITableView to reveal an UISearchController searchBar:

[image]

AFAIR this issue was not present in the first iOS 13.0 Beta releases.

Is this a new bug or do I need to implement UINavigationBarAppearance to prevent this behaviour (leaving the NavigationBar color unchanged)?

The screenshot is from a minimal App created using the Xcode Single View App template, then replacing the UIViewController by an UITableViewController embedded in an UINavigationController. The UITableViewController implementation is as follows:

```
import UIKit

class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

    let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        navigationItem.title = "Title"

        searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
        searchController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Search"
        navigationItem.searchController = searchController
        definesPresentationContext = true
    }

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 50
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = "row \(indexPath.row)"
        return cell
    }
}

extension TableViewController: UISearchResultsUpdating {
    func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Just noticed that my question was already asked before:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57746292/navigation-bar-becomes-white-when-a-uisearchcontroller-is-added-to-it
(I didn't find the first question on my initial search because it states that the NavigationBar turns white, which is not what actually happens).