# add uiColor for cgsize (swift3)

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uicolor, cgsize

Right now newSize just creates a white box. I would like newSize to be a blue box. How do I add uiColor to newSize?

```
          let newSize: CGSize = CGSize(width: 900, height: 900)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize)
```

Comment: Not exact duplicate but similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26542035/create-uiimage-with-solid-color-in-swift

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use your color setFill() method to define the color that you would like to fill your image context and just use a UIBezierPath to fill the desired area:

```
let newSize = CGSize(width: 900, height: 900)
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, false, 0)
defer { UIGraphicsEndImageContext() } 

UIColor.blue.setFill()
UIBezierPath(rect: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: newSize)).fill()

UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
```