# Change Tab Bar background transparency

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I am trying to make my Tab Bar in my tab bar controller to have a low opacity background, so it is semi transparent, i am trying to do this programatically, however the background changes to the correct color, but always appears solid, with no transparency.

Here is the code in my TabBarViewController

```
class TabBarViewController: UITabBarController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.tabBar.unselectedItemTintColor = UIColor(red: 17.0/255.0, green: 70.0/255.0, blue: 95.0/255.0, alpha: 0.4)
        self.tabBar.barTintColor = UIColor(red: 17.0/255.0, green: 70.0/255.0, blue: 95.0/255.0, alpha: 0.5)


        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

For such a case, you should generate a customized `UIImage` to the tab bar [*`backgroundimage`*](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitabbar/1623469-backgroundimage) property.

Let's assume that your desired color for your tab bar -that should be transparent- is black, you could implement in your custom `UITabBarController`:

```
class TabBarViewController: UITabBarController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let transperentBlackColor = UIColor(displayP3Red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.5)

        let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1, height: 1)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size, false, 0.0)
        transperentBlackColor.setFill()
        UIRectFill(rect)

        if let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext() {
            tabBar.backgroundImage = image
        }

        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    }
}
```

So, as an Output, if we assumed that the background color of your view controller is blue, it should looks like:

[image]

As shown, the tab bar is not purely black, it contains transparency (0.5) as expected.

Also, for checking how you could generate a solid-color `UIImage`, you could check this SO answer : [Create UIImage with solid color in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26542035/create-uiimage-with-solid-color-in-swift).

Answer (score 1):

Just replace `barTintColor` with `backgroundColor`.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()
     self.tabBar.unselectedItemTintColor = UIColor(red: 17.0/255.0, green: 70.0/255.0, blue: 95.0/255.0, alpha: 0.4)
     self.tabBar.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 17.0/255.0, green: 70.0/255.0, blue: 95.0/255.0, alpha: 0.5)
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, tried but still showing a solid color

Answer (score -2):

private func setTabbarOpacity() {
let transperentBlackColor = UIColor(displayP3Red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.75)
let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1, height: 1)
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size, false, 0.0)
transperentBlackColor.setFill()
UIRectFill(rect)

```
    if let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext() {
        tabBar.backgroundImage = image
    }
    
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).