# Swift UIButton background color does not change

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uibackgroundcolor

I have the the following custom cell:

```
class MyCell: UITableViewCell {

    func configure(title1: String, title2: String) {
        backgroundColor = .red

        let myView = MyView(frame: frame)
        myView.button1.setTitle(title1, for: .normal)
        myView.button2.setTitle(title2, for: .normal)

        addSubview(myView)
    }
}
```

and the custom view:

```
class MyView: UIView {
    var button1: UIButton!
    var button2: UIButton!

    override var backgroundColor: UIColor? {
        didSet {
            guard UIColor.clear.isEqual(backgroundColor) else { return }
            button1.setTitle("asldkfa")
            button1.backgroundColor = .blue
            button2.backgroundColor = .yellow
        }
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        button1 = UIButton()
        button2 = UIButton()
        button1.backgroundColor = .purple
        button2.backgroundColor = .brown
        backgroundColor = .gray

        let stackView = UIStackView(); stackView.distribution = .fill; stackView.alignment = .fill
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(button1)
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(button2)

        addSubview(stackView)
    }
}
```

I initialized the cell view within my `tableView:cellForRowAt` method like this:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! MyCell
cell.configure(title1: "Foo", title2: "Bla")
```

I get the following output in my tableView:

[image: table cell]

Every time the color of `MyView` is changed externally (for example when clicking on the cell), I want to colours of the buttons to change – that is why I have overridden the `didSet` observer of `backgroundColor` in `MyView`. Eventually I want those colours to be random, but here I am just trying to change `button1.backgroundColor = .blue`.

It does not work, the color of the buttons does not change. I have even tried changing the `tintColor` and it also does not work. Changing the title with `button1.setTitle(...)` does work, so I have no idea what is happening.

Does anyone have an idea?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

When I build the app, add `button1.setTitle("asldkfa", for: .normal)` inside the `didSet`, and click on the cell, this is the output:

[image]

Meaning that the `backgroundColor` is set, as the title does change, just not the colours.

**IMPORTANT**: There is no other code where the `backgroundColor` is changed explicitly and the `didSelectRowAt` method is not even implemented. When a cell is selected, the backgroundColor of its subviews is automatically updated, so that is how I am changing the color at the moment, by selecting the cell.

Comment: I don't see anywhere in your code that you actually modifying the background color of myView.

Comment: As I mention in the answer, just click on the cell. The `backgroundColor` is change to the selected one.

Comment: Can you show your selection code please?

Comment: I don't have selection code, I build the app, select the cell and it changes the color because it propagates it.

Comment: First, You probably might want to think about adding Button in your configure Method in your cell. Second, aren't you reloading your cell?

Comment: Okay, now I see the issue. Chaning background color of a cell doesn't mean it changes background color of myView added as a subview to a cell. You either need to override `setSelected` in your tableView cell, or use `didSelectRowAt` delegate method and change background color of `myView` programmatically.

Comment: @inokey please ready my question, when I add `button1.setTitle("blabla", for: .normal)` inside the `didSet` function it *changes* the title, meaning the `backgroundColor` does get set on click.

Comment: try putting your color changing code to `layoutSubviews()` method in `myView`

Comment: Have you checked the `frame` of `myView`? `let myView = MyView(frame: frame)` doesn't seem right.

Comment: @inokey that does not work :( The buttons work just fine, I can change sizes and title this way, only not background color.

Comment: are those buttons are plain UIButtons or they're custom buttons? Is there any chance that their class is somehow overriding the backgroundColor behaviour? Have you tried to put on a breakpoint in myView `init` method to check whether is not accidentally recreated, and thus resetting all the changes?

Comment: They are plain `UIButtons`. I just tried setting the breakpoint and it does not get triggered after clicking the cell. Also set a breakpoint in `cellForRowAt` and it also doesn't get triggered. Only the breakpoint inside `didSet` is triggered after clicking the cell.

Comment: where do you add the stackview as a subview? why are the buttons in the output picture u added are purple and brown? are you sure you are looking at the right cell? maybe you are looking at a cell from storyboard?

Comment: I managed to recreate the behaviour in the example, and still cannot figure out what's happening there. It seems like background colours of view is completely wiped out on selection, changing it to nil, and then back to the gray color.

Comment: use dispatch async

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Updated:* Instead of using the `UIButton`'s `backgroundColor` property, you actually want to be using `setBackgroundImage(_:for:)`. You can use an extension on `UIImage` ([extension example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26542035/create-uiimage-with-solid-color-in-swift)) to create an image from a color and that should work well for what you're trying to do.

Your resulting configuration code should look something like:

```
button1.setBackgroundImage(.image(with: .red), for: .normal)
```

Comment: `It is worth nothing that by setting a value for the property in the initializer of MyView after calling super.init(frame:) you will have already triggered didSet`  -- this part

Comment: The background colors can change as often as needed (will be random colors)so that’s not the problem. I don’t have code for cell selection. Will test out this code in a while. Thanks.

Comment: You may have simply omitted this in your example code, but as @Eyal mentioned, we also can't see where you're adding the StackView as a subview. Make sure you're not missing that :)

Comment: I had omitted that code because I thought it was not relevant. I have added it now. I also don't change the color every time, just when the cell is selected (`backgroundColor == UIColor.clear`). The code I update with your answer is here https://gist.github.com/lfcj/698b6983f10380016e21735391af8f2a and it also does not manage to change just the backgroundColor of the buttons.

Comment: I just posted an update (#2) abve — missed something before that is most likely the issue.

Comment: You should change your answer to set the `button1.backgroundImage(imageWithSolidColor, for: .normal)` within the `configure` method. Where the `imageWithSolidColor` is created according to first answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26542035/create-uiimage-with-solid-color-in-swift
Please update and I will mark as answer.

Answer (score -3):

Actually, the problem is it didSet you added the color so while changing it will remain the same you should do like this

```
 override var backgroundColor: UIColor? {
    didSet {
        button1.backgroundColor = backgroundColor
        button2.backgroundColor = backgroundColor
    }
}
```

Comment: But I don't want the `backgroundColor`, I want another random color.

Comment: You can not this and there is no purpose for doing this because while initializing you changing the color.

Comment: I don't care about the initial colours, I care about changing the cololor when the superview changes its own color. How do I do that?

Comment: Just FYI: it is possible, just instead of the `backgroundColor`, one has to set `setBackgroundImage`.