# Removing UIImage background from UISegmentedControl [Storyboard]

Tags: swift, uikit, uisegmentedcontrol

I have a SegmententedControl that was added using Storyboards and I want to remove the default greyish background. The images are snippets from the View Hierarchy Debugger.

[image]

[image]

Comment: why do you want to remove it?

Comment: This should help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58285960/11774595

Comment: I have a custom appearance setup but I think the background is interferring. The customization was setup for a programmatic segmented control used elsewhere, but this view was setup in storyboards.