# How to set transparent color or image for UIControlSegment from iOS 13?

Tags: swift, uikit, uisegmentedcontrol, ios13

I have been following multiple examples on the internet regarding the customization of the new `UIControlSegment` from iOS 13 but none of them are explaining how to set its background color transparent. I have a very soft gradient in my app and I cannot set it to transparent anymore. I have tried to apply a layer to try to fix it but no success, the whole component is getting trimmed or it's affecting superior layers.

All examples on the internet are basically the same, with white background or black. This is not nice when you are giving maintenance in a colorful app.

[image]
*(I need to set the gray background to transparent or gradient)*

My manager doesn't want to change the app layout and we don't have time for it now.

I have tried to follow this tutorial, but no success: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56458794/2430555

By setting `segmentedControl.backgroundColor = UIColor.white` you don't get a white background. This doesn't make sense.

Thank you.

Comment: Why can't you set the background color to UIColor.clear?

Comment: It doesn't work. The background keeps getting dark.

Comment: @LoupG 
Here you can see the color difference, note that the rect at the middle is a divider with color set UIColor.clear.
The bottom and top colors are what it should be. Note that the middle is darker than the colors outside.
 
https://imgur.com/a/CP4qwUX

Comment: It's clear that Apple is causing a color deviation.

Comment: @PedroPauloAmorim The link in your question is essentially what you need. Apply whatever background image you want (clear, gradient). If it's not working then update your question showing what you actually tried.

Comment: It's not. Notice that this script modifies the component to look like the iOS12 one.