# How to customize background color and corner radius of UISegmentedControl in iOS 13?

Tags: swift, uisegmentedcontrol, ios13

I realize that setting `backgroundColor` for UISegmentedControl in iOS 13 makes nothing changes. In additional, i would like to customize the corner radius but unlikely `layer.cornerRadius` doesnt work neither.

Here is what i am trying to do:

```
if (@available(iOS 13.0, *)) {
    unitSegmentedControl.selectedSegmentTintColor = [UIColor greenColor];
}
unitSegmentedControl.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
unitSegmentedControl.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
unitSegmentedControl.layer.cornerRadius = unitSegmentedControl.height/2;
unitSegmentedControl.layer.borderWidth = 1;
unitSegmentedControl.layer.borderColor = unitSegmentedControl.tintColor.CGColor;
```

Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/56458794/1226963 for ideas.