# How to create border in UIButton?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I use custom button in my app named "addButton" and I want to border it with white color how can i get the white color border around my custom button?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add border and shadow to the buttons](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7923443/add-border-and-shadow-to-the-buttons)

Answer (score 364, accepted):

You can set the border properties on the CALayer by accessing the layer property of the button.

First, add Quartz

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

Set properties:

```
myButton.layer.borderWidth = 2.0f;
myButton.layer.borderColor = [UIColor greenColor].CGColor;
```

See:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/calayer#//apple_ref/occ/cl/CALayer

The CALayer in the link above allows you to set other properties like corner radius, maskToBounds etc...

Also, a good article on button fun:

https://web.archive.org/web/20161221132308/http://www.apptite.be/tutorial_custom_uibuttons.php

Comment: Make sure you link your target to the QuartCore framework in the Build Phases tab of the target editor.

Comment: Do I need to import quartz ? I can still access layer of button without it. My purpose of asking is : what benefits are we getting when importing Quartz

Comment: plus 1 for using `CGColor`

Answer (score 53):

Its very simple, just add the quartzCore header in your file(for that you have to add the quartz framework to your project)

and then do this

```
[[button layer] setCornerRadius:8.0f];

[[button layer] setMasksToBounds:YES];

[[button layer] setBorderWidth:1.0f];
```

you can change the float values as required.

enjoy.

---

Here's some typical modern code ...

```
self.buttonTag.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;
self.buttonCancel.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;

self.buttonTag.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blueColor].CGColor;
self.buttonCancel.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blueColor].CGColor;

self.buttonTag.layer.cornerRadius = 4.0f;
self.buttonCancel.layer.cornerRadius = 4.0f;
```

that's a similar look to segmented controls.

> UPDATE for Swift:

- No need to add "QuartzCore"

Just do:

```
button.layer.cornerRadius = 8.0
button.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
button.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
```

Answer (score 25):

And in swift, you don't need to import "QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h"

Just use:

```
button.layer.borderWidth = 0.8
button.layer.borderColor = (UIColor( red: 0.5, green: 0.5, blue:0, alpha: 1.0 )).cgColor
```

or

```
button.layer.borderWidth = 0.8
button.layer.borderColor = UIColor.grayColor().cgColor
```

Comment: According to XCode 9, "CGColor has been renamed cgColor".

Answer (score 22):

The problem setting the layer's `borderWidth` and `borderColor` is that the when you touch the button the border doesn't animate the highlight effect.

Of course, you can observe the button's events and change the border color accordingly but that feels unnecessary.

Another option is to create a stretchable UIImage and setting it as the button's background image. You can create an Image set in your Images.xcassets like this:

[image: Images.xcassets]

Then, you set it as the button's background image:

[image: Button properties]

If your image is a template image you can set tint color of the button and the border will change:

[image: Final Button]

Now the border will highlight with the rest of the button when touched.

Comment: What do you make the Image out of?

Comment: To make that image I used Sketch, but you can use Gimp, Illustrator, Photoshop...

Comment: Nice answer. It's better than change layer's `borderWidth`.

Answer (score 9):

Here's an updated version (**Swift 3.0.1**) from Ben Packard's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38999397/3211335).

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable class BorderedButton: UIButton {

    @IBInspectable var borderColor: UIColor? {
        didSet {
            if let bColor = borderColor {
                self.layer.borderColor = bColor.cgColor
            }
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var borderWidth: CGFloat = 0 {
        didSet {
            self.layer.borderWidth = borderWidth
        }
    }

    override var isHighlighted: Bool {
        didSet {
            guard let currentBorderColor = borderColor else {
                return
            }

            let fadedColor = currentBorderColor.withAlphaComponent(0.2).cgColor

            if isHighlighted {
                layer.borderColor = fadedColor
            } else {

                self.layer.borderColor = currentBorderColor.cgColor

                let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "borderColor")
                animation.fromValue = fadedColor
                animation.toValue = currentBorderColor.cgColor
                animation.duration = 0.4
                self.layer.add(animation, forKey: "")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The resulting button can be used inside your StoryBoard thanks to the `@IBDesignable` and `@IBInspectable` tags.

[image]

Also the two properties defined, allow you to set the border width and color directly on interface builder and preview the result.

[image]

Other properties could be added in a similar fashion, for border radius and highlight fading time.

Comment: I've problems with the constraints over swift 4,I did full size button ( side to side in the width) , In the xcode I saw border preview very well, but over the emulator or device I saw the border reduced to the size of the text inside of button, The only autolayout constraint that I added was the centered horizontally , how fix it? thanks!

Comment: @CristianChaparroA. The reason is that `prepareForInterfaceBuilder` only gets called from IB, not when you run the app. So also set the UIEdgeInsets in `awakeFromNib`, then it will show also when running the app.

Answer (score 8):

To change button Radius, Color and Width I set like this:

```
self.myBtn.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
self.myBtn.layer.borderWidth = 1;
self.myBtn.layer.borderColor =[UIColor colorWithRed:189.0/255.0f green:189.0/255.0f blue:189.0/255.0f alpha:1.0].CGColor;
```

Answer (score 8):

**This can be achieved in various methods in Swift 3.0 Worked on Latest version August - 2017**

> **Option 1:**

**Directly assign the borderWidth property values for UI Button:**

```
  btnUserButtonName.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
```

**Set Title with Default Color values for UI Button:**

```
btnUserButtonName.setTitleColor(UIColor.darkGray, for: .normal)
```

**Set Border with Default Color for the border property values for UI Button:**

```
btnUserButtonName.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red
```

**Set user defined Color for the border property values for UI Button:**

```
   let myGrayColor = UIColor(red: 0.889415, green: 0.889436, blue:0.889424, alpha: 1.0 )
   btnUserButtonName.layer.borderColor = myGrayColor.cgColor
```

> **Option 2: [Recommended]**

Use the Extension method, so the Button through out the application will be looking consistent and no need to repeat multiple lines of code every where.

```
//Create an extension class in any of the swift file

extension UIButton {
func setBordersSettings() {
        let c1GreenColor = (UIColor(red: -0.108958, green: 0.714926, blue: 0.758113, alpha: 1.0))
        self.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0
        self.layer.borderColor = c1GreenColor.cgColor
        self.setTitleColor(c1GreenColor, for: .normal)
        self.layer.masksToBounds = true
    }
}
```

**Usage in code:**

```
//use the method and call whever the border has to be applied

btnUserButtonName.setBordersSettings()
```

**Output of Extension method Button:**

[image]

Answer (score 7):

You don't need to import `QuartzCore.h` now. Taking iOS 8 sdk and Xcode 6.1 in referrence.

Directly use:

```
[[myButton layer] setBorderWidth:2.0f];
[[myButton layer] setBorderColor:[UIColor greenColor].CGColor];
```

Answer (score 7):

Here's a `UIButton` subclass that supports the highlighted state animation without using images. It also updates the border color when the view's tint mode changes.

```swift
class BorderedButton: UIButton {
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        layer.borderColor = tintColor.cgColor
        layer.borderWidth = 1
        layer.cornerRadius = 5

        contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 5, left: 10, bottom: 5, right: 10)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("NSCoding not supported")
    }

    override func tintColorDidChange() {
        super.tintColorDidChange()

        layer.borderColor = tintColor.cgColor
    }

    override var isHighlighted: Bool {
        didSet {
            let fadedColor = tintColor.withAlphaComponent(0.2).cgColor

            if isHighlighted {
                layer.borderColor = fadedColor
            } else {
                layer.borderColor = tintColor.cgColor

                let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "borderColor")
                animation.fromValue = fadedColor
                animation.toValue = tintColor.cgColor
                animation.duration = 0.4
                layer.add(animation, forKey: nil)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

`let button = BorderedButton(style: .System) //style .System is important`

Appearance:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Swift 5

```
button.layer.borderWidth = 2
```

To change the colour of the border use

```
button.layer.borderColor = CGColor(srgbRed: 255/255, green: 126/255, blue: 121/255, alpha: 1)
```

Comment: button.layer.borderColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor is acceptable too!

Answer (score 3):

****In Swift 3****

To create border

```
 btnName.layer.borderWidth = 1
 btnName.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
```

To make corner rounded

```
 btnName.layer.cornerRadius = 5
```

Answer (score 2):

Update with Swift 3

```
    button.layer.borderWidth = 0.8
    button.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

(Swift 5) You can add this extension as a common method to create and customize any kind of `UIView / UIImage / UIButton`.

```
extension UIView {
    func makeViewBorderStyle(cornerRadius: CGFloat = 8, borderWidth: CGFloat = 1, color: UIColor = UIColor.lightGray){
        self.layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius
        self.layer.borderWidth = borderWidth
        var borderColor = color
        if borderColor == UIColor.lightGray{
            if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
                borderColor = UIColor.systemGray3
            } else {
                borderColor = UIColor.lightGray
            }
        }
        self.layer.borderColor = borderColor.cgColor
    }
}
```

You just need to call the common method like this -->

```
@IBOutlet weak private var submitButton: UIButton!

override func viewDidLoad() {
        self.submitButton.makeViewBorderStyle()
    }
```

If you want to customize the border, you just need to pass the value you want like -->

```
self.submitButton.makeViewBorderStyle(cornerRadius: 12, borderWidth: 2, color: .red)
```