# UIButton UIControlEventTouchUpInside triggering event even when picking up finger outside of button frame

Tags: ios, ios7, uibutton

I need to have a button on my iPhone app that triggers the event only when the user touches up inside the frame area.

As far as I understand `UIControlEventTouchUpInside` should do it, and for the most part it does: if I drag my finger on the screen far enough from the frame, and only then lifts it up, the event isn't triggered (which is the behavior I'm looking for.)

But if I lift up my finger just outside the frame, the event is triggered anyway. Is there a way to prevent it?

```
UIButton *selectPlan = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
selectPlan.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.bounds.size.width/2-buttonWidthHeight/2, self.view.bounds.size.height/2-buttonWidthHeight/2 + 43, buttonWidthHeight, buttonWidthHeight);
[selectPlan addTarget:self action:@selector(checkIfPlansExistAndFindBestPlan) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[selectPlan setTitle:@"Select Plan" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.view addSubview:selectPlan];
```

Comment: I don't think that should happen... can you check frame of button by giving border to UIButton... (http://stackoverflow.com/a/8162518/1066828)

Comment: I tested your code in iOS 6 and 7.1 and works perfectly. Tested in Simulator and touch with mouse arrow.

Comment: @FahimParkar I did. It does happen.

Comment: @Gabriel.Massana, are you sure? Try dragging the cursor just outside of the button border, don't go too far with it.

Comment: It works perfect in my Simulator

Comment: @Eddy : restart mac once... :(

Comment: @FahimParkar It doesn't work. I have also tested on the phone. Same effect. There's clearly an invisible rim around the buttons in which a drag out still counts as "in."

Comment: provide screenshot from simulator... or upload sample project on dropbox or github... better upload sample project...

Comment: @FahimParkar there you go. Notice that you have to drag the finger a certain distance from the button so that the event doesn't trigger. https://www.dropbox.com/s/8il7ljejpek96f9/ButtonDemo.zip

Comment: @Eddy : this seems default nature of UIButton. If you want exact locations, use touchEvents...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is default nature of UIButton. You cannot change it.

From the button name I understand, you have plan and when use choose plan you want to find which button is clicked.

I would say for more accuracy use `touchesBegan` and `touchesEnd` events.

Below is sample link for those events.

http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Example_iOS_5_iPhone_Touch,_Multitouch_and_Tap_Application