# How To Access All UIButtons within a UIScrollView within a UIView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I am using the following to try to access all the UIButtons located inside of a UIScrollView within a UIView. The problem is that the code doesn't seem to locate the buttons and set the border property.

UIView -> UIScrollView -> UIButtons.

I basically want to loop through the buttons and set the border property.

```
for(UIView *v in [self.viewLightLeakChoices subviews]) {

    if([v isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {

        v.layer.borderWidth = 0;

    }

}
```

Comment: Your code is working fine with xCode 6.1 and target SDK 7.1

Comment: `viewLightLeakChoices` is `UIScrollView` or `UIView` ?

Comment: are you sure you are reaching the uibutton

Comment: try this once 
 CALayer *btnlayer=v.layer;
btnlayer.borderWidth=0;

Comment: OP, you're getting a lot of answers that are making this issue way more complicated than it actually is, but I think answering @Chinttu-Maddy-Ramani's question might be the key to unlocking this... Specifically, you need to make sure you're looping through your *scrollview* subviews, not your *view* subviews.

Comment: Thanks for the comments viewLightLeakChoices is the UIView and not the UIScrollView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the help guys. I ended up doing a bunch of for loops to get down to the UIButtons.

```
for(UIView *v in [self.viewLightLeakChoices subviews]) {

    if([v isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class]]) {

        for(UIView *subView in [v subviews]) {

            for(UIButton *btn in [subView subviews]) {

                btn.layer.borderWidth = 0;

            }

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: But I thought you only had one UIScrollView... ?  If so, you could just replace  [self.viewLightLeakChoices subviews] with [self.yourScrollView subviews] in your original code.

Comment: if you have only one scrollview then assign tag to scrollview and access directly with tag . so now no use for `for(UIView *v in [self.viewLightLeakChoices subviews]) ` and use like `UIScrollView *scrlV = [viewLightLeakChoices viewWithTag:1000];` set tag as you want.and after that `for(UIButton *subView in [scrlV subviews])`

Answer (score 2):

Try this one instead

```
for (id obj in scrollView.subviews) {

    NSString *classStr = NSStringFromClass([obj class]);

    if ([classStr isEqualToString:@"UIButton"]) {
        UIButton *button = (UIButton*)obj;
        button.layer.borderWidth = 2.0;
        button.layer.borderColor = [UIColor greenColor].CGColor;
    }
}
```

output

[image]

Answer (score 1):

first make sure you are getting subviews of `UIScrollView` because your structure is

UIView > UIScrollView> UIButton

if you have only 1 scroll view in `self.viewLightLeakChoices` then set your scrollview tag = 1000 and direct access your scrollview so now you dont need to use loop. and execution will be fast.

```
UIScrollView *scrlV = [self.viewLightLeakChoices viewWithTag:1000];
for (UIButton *btn in scrlV.subviews) 
{
    if ([btn isKindOfClass:[UIButton Class]]) {
        btn.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;
        btn.layer.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i am unable to get i am expecting you are having scrollview -> uiview ->button

```
 for(UIView *myview in Scrollview.subviews)
{

    for ( id mybutton in myview.subviews)
    {
        if ([mybutton isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
        {
            UIButton *mybtn=(UIButton *)mybutton;
            mybtn.layer.borderWidth=0;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You should have create Button class say MyButton extents UIButton, if you do this there is no need to loop through scrollview's subviews.

implement awakeFromNib method and apply border, to apply border refer this SO Post [How to create border in UIButton?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8162411/how-to-create-border-in-uibutton)