# objective c How to access and change dynamically created button background color in a uiscrollview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

As you can see in the screenshot I have created multiple buttons dynamically in a UI scroll view. Every button actually holds a date action upon which specific events to that date loads into table. UI Scroll view is global element in the code which can be accessed by any method in the controller.

What I wanted now is access a button (when someone chooses a date to see events on that date) in that scrollview and change its background color. For your convenience I have added the whole code for date and scrollview. Please also note that data are loading from remote server.

Link to the screenshot is as follows
[image]

Please forgive me if you see anything wrong in typing. This is my first question in stack.

```
     luckyDateScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(22, 2, lucky_screen_width-45, 23)];
     luckyDateScrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;

     CGFloat paperWidth = 50;
     int numberOfPapers = [dateRanges count];

     for (int i=0; i<[dateRanges count]; i++) {
              //NSLog(@"%d: %@", i, dateRange[i]);

              //php like exploding with separator |
              NSArray *dateString = [dateRanges[i] componentsSeparatedByString:@"|"];


              UIButton *btn = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake( 5+ (paperWidth+4) * i , 0, paperWidth, luckyDateScrollView.bounds.size.height)];
              btn.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:11.0f];
              [btn setTitle: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",dateString[0]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

              //dateResendButton
              [btn setTag:i];
              [btn addTarget:self
                      action:@selector(byDateFilterButton:)
            forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

            if([today isEqualToString:dateString[1]]){
                [GlobalMethods makeRoundedView:btn WithColorString:@"#ffffff" BGColorString:@"#004D00"];
            }else{
              [GlobalMethods makeRoundedView:btn WithColorString:@"#ffffff" BGColorString:GlobalVariables.initGV.BlackColor];
            }


              //[GlobalMethods makeRoundedView:btn WithColorString:@"#ffffff" BGColorString:@"#FF0000"];
              [luckyDateScrollView addSubview:btn];
     }



     contentSize = CGSizeMake( 10 + (paperWidth+4) * numberOfPapers, luckyDateScrollView.bounds.size.height);
     luckyDateScrollView.contentSize = contentSize;

     //         [GlobalMethods makeRoundedView:aScrollView WithColorString:@"#ffffff" BGColorString:GlobalVariables.initGV.BlackColor];

     [dateUIView addSubview:luckyDateScrollView];

     luckyDateBtnLeftScroll = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 2, 20, 23)];
     [luckyDateBtnLeftScroll setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"arrow_g_icon_left"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
     [luckyDateBtnLeftScroll addTarget:self action:@selector(dateSetScrollToLeft:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

     [dateUIView addSubview:luckyDateBtnLeftScroll];

     luckyDateBtnRightScroll = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(lucky_screen_width-25, 2, 20, 23)];
     [luckyDateBtnRightScroll setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"arrow_g_icon"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
     [luckyDateBtnRightScroll addTarget:self action:@selector(dateSetScrollToRight:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

     [dateUIView addSubview:luckyDateBtnRightScroll];

     //ViewCollapse.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithCGColor: @"#FFD80D"];
```

Comment: Welcome to the stackoverflow. You can upload your image on any image hosting website (like imgur.com) and post a link here.

Comment: Thank you atulkhatri. I have added the screenshot here...http://imgur.com/8ptWTRA

Comment: Sorry this is the direct link http://i.imgur.com/8ptWTRA.png?1

Comment: @TusherSuvro Edit your question and add the picture there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly you can simply change the background of your button in the `byDateFilterButton:` method. It should have a `sender` parameter which would be the button in question.
If you also need to change the background of the other buttons back to normal, you need to keep a reference to them, probably in an array (or dictionary - if you have many buttons and need fast access).

Comment: yes. You are right pajevic. I have modified code this way. Thanks

Comment: I m glad I could help. If the answer helped you solve your problem please mark this by accepting it.

Answer (score 0):

I modified byDateFilterButton method in a following way. Thanks to this SO post [Access all buttons in uiscollview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27039944/how-to-access-all-uibuttons-within-a-uiscrollview-within-a-uiview)

```
    for (id obj in luckyDateScrollView.subviews) {

    NSString *classStr = NSStringFromClass([obj class]);

    if ([classStr isEqualToString:@"UIButton"]) {
        UIButton *button = (UIButton*)obj; //NSLog(@"buttonn tag %ld",(long)button.tag);

        if(sender.tag == button.tag){ // currently selected button
          [GlobalMethods makeRoundedView:button WithColorString:@"#ffffff" BGColorString:@"#555454"];
        }
        else{ // the rest of buttons
          [GlobalMethods makeRoundedView:button WithColorString:@"#ffffff" BGColorString:GlobalVariables.initGV.BlackColor];
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Yes, this will work. I guess how you choose to do it is a matter of preference. Personally, I feel it's cleaner to keep a reference to the buttons in an array then iterating through all of the scrollview's subviews, as you don't have the overhead of the class check and looping over the other subviews (especially if there are many of those). I do have a few pointers though. First, a better way of checking the class would be simply using the method `[obj isMemberOfClass:UIButton.class] ` or `[obj isKindOfClass:UIButton.class]` if you also want to include subclasses.

Comment: Second, you don't need the tags to test the object. Simply using `sender == button` will do it as this comparison uses the object reference, essentially telling you if the two objects are one and the same object. Note that this is only the case for objects; using `==` on primitives (like `int` and `float`) still checks the value.

Comment: Thank you again pajevic. Yeah I modified the code with your suggestion. It still works same. Thanks for this cleaner suggestion. :-)