# add image and text on button programmatically

Tags: iphone, ios

I want an image and text "View Details" 
in my button(red color button) programmatically...
image is on left side of button and text on right side..

```
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
[aButton setImage:img forState:UIControlStateNormal];
aButton.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor]; 
//[img release]; i am not sure i release it or not  
//[testBtn setTitleEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(70.0, -150.0, 5.0, 5.0)];
// what the above lines  line work? 
[aButton setTitle:@"View Details" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

I see the button but not, red color button...only red color corners...

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2808888/is-it-even-possible-to-change-a-uibuttons-background-color

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you make image of button having red color and text on it..and set the image on it...

This is the code for setting the image on button..

`[but1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"LeftBack.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal]`;//setting image on button.

Answer (score 1):

```
USE buttonOBJ.contentHorizontalAlignment=UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentLeft
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you post a code for creating a button? Maybe you have it as a RoundRectButton, try CustomButton instead.

Answer (score -1):

Use of imageNamed is not recommended due to memory issues. prefer using instead loading the image from file like this:

```
NSString *path = [[NSString alloc]  initWithFormat:@"%@/%@", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath], @"fileName.png"];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path];
[path release], path = nil;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
NSString *path = [[NSString alloc]  initWithFormat:@"%@/%@", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath], @"fileName.png"];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path];
[path release], path = nil;
```