# Custom UIButton Color in MonoTouch

Tags: c#, ios, mono, xamarin.ios, uibutton

I'm having trouble programmatically hard coding a color in for a `UIButton` using MonoTouch. The standard RectRound buttons are white and I need this button to be blue. Here is my code:

```
     private void CreateButton() {
        RectangleF viewFrame = this.subView.Frame;
        RectangleF buttonFrame = new RectangleF (10f, viewFrame.Bottom - 200f, viewFrame.Width - 20f, 50f);

        this.buttonChangeColor = UIButton.FromType (UIButtonType.RoundedRect);
        this.buttonChangeColor.Frame = buttonFrame;
        this.buttonChangeColor.SetTitle ("Tap to change view color", UIControlState.Normal);
        this.buttonChangeColor.SetTitle ("Changing color...", UIControlState.Highlighted);
        this.buttonChangeColor.SetTitleColor (UIColor.Red, UIControlState.Normal);
 //This here is my attempt. The rounded rectangle remains white and I can see some blue peeking out from behind but I need the button to be blue, not the background
        this.buttonChangeColor.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Blue; 
        this.buttonChangeColor.TouchUpInside += this.buttonChangeColor_TouchUpInside;
        this.subView.AddSubview (this.buttonChangeColor);

    }
```

Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [Is it even possible to change a UIButtons background color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2808888/is-it-even-possible-to-change-a-uibuttons-background-color)

It explains why, for `UIButtonType.RoundedRect`, you won't be able to change the background color as you would expect. I.e. You'll need to create a `Custom` button and duplicate the rounded-rect look.

Answer (score 1):

I have done this in my previos anwser to post so check link that i paste
[change UIButton Color dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9733213/how-to-change-background-color-in-monotouch/11753717#11753717)