# How to change backgroundcolor of uibutton programmatically

Tags: ios, uibutton, uikit

How would I change the background color of a button to black?

Comment: Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2808888/is-it-even-possible-to-change-a-uibuttons-background-color

Comment: see this thread

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2808888/is-it-even-possible-to-change-a-uibuttons-background-color/2809237#2809237

Answer (score 3):

If you want to programatically change the colour of button you will have to make the type of button as custom as :-

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:uibuttontypecustom];
note "uibuttontypecustom"
```

and then you can change backgroung by `[btn setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];` or you can set a black backgroung image by using `steImage` method on `btn`.

Answer (score 2):

I think this will help you,

```
[button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

Answer (score 2):

Mr/Ms Baiju please review below my code,

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
button.frame = CGRectMake(10, 200, 300, 40);
[button setTitle:@"Button" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonAction) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
[button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.view addSubview: button];
```

I think it will help you to set background color and set background image for a button. If you want to set image please change the button type `RoundedRect to Custom`. I hope it will help you little bit. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use this line of code and try use any color image .

```
[myButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: is this really the only way to do it? if so, xcode is greatly lacking in options. although many of us already knew that

Answer (score 1):

If anyone wants to know how to make same thing in swift with full code then here it is...Just write this code in your ViewController.swift

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController
{ 
    var firstbutton:UIButton? //firstbutton = Your Button Name

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.firstbutton = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.Custom) as? UIButton
        self.firstbutton!.frame = CGRectMake(100, 200, 100, 100)

        //This Line is used for color of your button

        self.firstbutton!.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
        self.view.addSubview(firstbutton!)
    }

    //This section is used to bring the button in front of everything on the view

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        self.view.bringSubviewToFront(self.firstbutton!)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

in your XIB drag and drop a button. got to button properties in your right hand side and **set button type to custom**. (Or you can do than in code too). In your .h file create `UIButton * btn;` and bind it to the XIB.

Then go to .m file and in viewdidload method right this code.

```
[btn setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
```

Thanks :)

Comment: this is the same answer as above, and it didnt work when i tried it his way either. also, the question was asking how to do it programmatically. that implies no use of IB at all

Answer (score 0):

Change the layer colour e.g.  self.btn.layer.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;